# react-native not rendering the response of axios response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, use-effect

I have written  an axios request in react-native  useEffect.The request is succesfull in backend  and returning a the right response in terminal.But the useEffect hook is not working according to it .It is still returning product as undefined and not changing the state.
If it all works well the product would contain the product variable.
It only works when I save it again and then it shows the product . Am I missing something here ?
Thanks in Advance !!

```
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(); 

useEffect(  () => {

      getproductinfo()

     if (props.editMode) {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt")
          .then((res) => {
            setToken(res);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  
      }
   console.log(product, "this is product");     
    },
    [],
  
)
```

this is my function

```
  const getproductinfo = async () => { 
    await axios
     .get(`${baseURL}products/get/product/${props.product}`)
     .then((res)=> {setProduct(res.data) 
       
     })
     .catch((error)=> { 
       console.log(error);
       console.log("this is order card product card error ") 
 
     }); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getproductinfo` is an async function and you don't use await in the useEffect hook so the code continues to run while the axios request is not yet resolved. However you can't use an async function as useEffect so I suggest the following approach

```js
useEffect(  () => {
    const asyncFunction = async() {
        await getproductinfo();
        console.log(product, "this is product"); 
    }
    asyncFunction();
    // Rest of your code....
    },
    [],
  
)
```

Comment: doesnt solve the problem it is not rendering the response

Comment: Well is product defined? Didn't know if it should render, because that wasn't in your question. Please post your full code

Comment: did that , thanks for pointing out